# How can I effectively copy a production site to a local XAMPP copy?

Tags: 8, migrations

I have a working live Drupal 8 website and it's still in its early stages.
I need to start theming the website, so I needed a local copy of it on my Windows PC. I installed XAMPP, copied the website, exported and imported the database and cleared the cache_*, sessions and watchdog tables.

The site is currently working nicely as expected, but I cannot log in as administrator. It keeps rejecting my password to the point that I changed the password from the database using a hashed password, but that didn't work, and now the account is temporarily blocked.

What could I've missed?

N.B. : I'm logging in from a login block on the front page (localhost:1234/Sites/d8dev/).

When I sign in, the failing sign in text appears in a link similar to localhost:1234/Sites/d8dev/node?destination=/Sites/d8dev/node.

Also note that this 'failing sign in' page looks terribly un-styled, like there's no or incomplete CSS styles are applied to it.

What am I missing?